# javax bean validation not working on method parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

javax validation not working on method parameters.. This is a test code and none of javax validation works on method parameter...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, params = "action=testAction")
public Test update(
        @Size(min = 1) @RequestBody List<String> ids,
        @Min(3) @PathVariable String name) {
    return doSomething(ids, name);
}
```

But i have class level validations which works perfectly...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public RoleType create (@RequestBody @Validated(FieldType.class) User user) {
    ...
}
```

And

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 10, groups = { FieldType.class }, message = "Invalid user code")
 public String getId() {
    return _id  ;
}
```

**-- Solution --**

all steps followed as per the accepted answer. 
And another addition is annoation on class level

```
@Validated
class UserController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, params ="action=testAction")
   public Test update(@Size(min = 1) @RequestBody List<String> ids,@Min(3) @PathVariable String name) {
    return doSomething(ids, name);
}
}
```

Comment: I just added @Validated in my class and it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to register [MethodValidationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) bean to kick method level validation annotation

> delegates to a JSR-303 provider for performing method-level
>   validation on annotated methods.

```
  @Bean
     public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
          return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
     }
```

then,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Test update(
        @Size(min = 1) @RequestBody List<String> ids,
        @Min(3) @PathVariable("id") String name) {
    return doSomething(ids, name);
}
```

if you want to handle validation exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
 @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
 public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
      Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
      StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
           strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
      }
      return strBuilder.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that elaborate answer, i forgot to add that bean configuration and another thing is i forgot to add @validated annotation on class level.. Now it works.

Comment: Apart from this you need to add @Validated to Type level in this case class else validation will not get triggered.